# Search for contact based on email address using People API

Tags: java, google-api, google-people-api

Is it any way to determine if user Contacts contains entry with specific email address?

Currently, People API allows only to get specific contact (based on resourceName - https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) or list all existing contacts (https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list).

I would like to know if user has specific email in contacts yet.
Is it possible without listing all existing contacts and iterating of this list? Do you know any workaround?

Comment: Any update on this? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to search through contacts using the class [`PeopleService.People.SearchContacts`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-people/latest/com/google/api/services/people/v1/PeopleService.People.SearchContacts.html). You need to [set the query](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-people/latest/com/google/api/services/people/v1/PeopleService.People.SearchContacts.html#setQuery-java.lang.String-) with the specific email address provided. The query matches on a contact's `names`, `nickNames`, `emailAddresses`, `phoneNumbers`, and `organizations` fields that are from the CONTACT source.

```
PeopleService service = new PeopleService.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();

// Request lorem@ipsum.com
SearchResponse response = service.people()
        .searchContacts()
        .setQuery("lorem@ipsum.com")
        .setPageSize(10)
        .setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses")
        .execute();
```